# Django 'could not parse remainder' on related model call in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-template-filters, templatetags

When I try to call this in my **template**

```
{% if member.departments.relationship(department).is_manager is True %}
```

I get this **error**

```
Could not parse the remainder: '(department).is_manager' from 'member.departments.relationship(department).is_manager'
```

---

But the same call works when I debug my view

```
(Pdb) member.departments.relationship(department).is_manager
True
```

Here is my view

```
def department_detail(request, uid):
  department = Department.nodes.get(uid=uid)
  return render(request, 'department/detail.html', {'department': department,})
```

Comment: Well the Django template languages deliberately does not use Python language, but a mini language that is limited, to prevent people (like you) to write business logic in templates.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it looks more complex than it is, I'm just trying to add an icon next to a name if someone is a manager.

Comment: Can you share the models? I think you can probably rewrite the logic here.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry, no i cannot =( they are not standard ORM. i am looking into a custom templatetag

Comment: Where is `member` being passed into the template?

Comment: @Cole It is not. department has members

Answer (score 0):

To solve it, I made use of templatetags. Fun and powerful to learn:

- Added /templatetags to same directory as models.py
- Added /templatetags/**init**.py
- Added /templatetags/department_extras.py

**department_extras.py:**

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def check_is_manager(member, department):
  if member.departments.relationship(department).is_manager is True:
    html_response = """<i class="fa fa-user-tie" title="Manager"></i>"""
  else:
    html_response = ""
  return mark_safe(html_response)
```

**then in template:**

```
{% load department_extras %}
{{member|check_is_manager:department}}
```

*Disclaimer*: If I was using a standard ORM then I would not have this problem, and I am only using it for visual effect, not business logic. If it weren't for the fact that 3 views and other models will need the same functionality, then I would have passed in an additional argument to the template.

I like templatetags because they are almost like sub-views that can act as common denominators across views so that you don't have to keep passing in supplemental data in your arguments of each view.